# Open popup from another function - Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I want to open my popup when ajaxCall function is called.

**Like this:**

```
function ajaxCall()
{

 openPopup();

}

function openPopup()
{

$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({

type: 'inline',
modal: false,

});

$(document).on('click', '.closePopup', function (e) 
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.magnificPopup.close();
            });

}
```

**Here is the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/33/

I want this popup to open when ajaxCall function is called.

Here is the working fiddle for onclick button open popup:

http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/27/

Comment: $.magnificPopup is not a function -->error ! please rectify

Comment: Please check my post now. I have added a working fiddle which works on onclick button

Comment: and your ajax function?

Comment: No need of ajax function here. I just want this popup to be opened when ajaxCall function is called.

Answer (score 7):

Use the open() function

```
function openPopup(el) { // get the class name in arguments here
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: '#thanksModal',
                },
                type: 'inline'
            });
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t5f5e5zw/2/

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the class name of clicked button in the function:

```
function openPopup(el) { // get the class name in arguments here
   $('.'+el).magnificPopup({ // use it here
      type: 'inline',
      modal: false
   });
}

$(function () {
   $('.ajax-call').click(function (e) {
      openPopup(this.className); //<----pass the clicked button's class name
   });
   $(document).on('click', '.closePopup', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.magnificPopup.close();
   });
});
```

#### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/35/)

Answer (score 0):

`magnificPopup is not a function` error. 
Please include any custom js files in your header section.

Comment: Please check my post now. I have added a working fiddle which works on onclick button

Comment: Yeah its working now but what error are you getting while calling `ajaxCall()`?

Comment: I dont want to bind it onbutton click. I want this popup to be open when ever ajaxCall() gets called. Here is the fiddle what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/qweWa/33/ but its not opening my popup

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function openPopup()
        {

            $('.ajax-call').magnificPopup({

            type: 'inline',
            modal: true,

        });

        /*$.magnificPopup({



 type: 'inline',
        modal: false,

    });*/

    $(document).on('click', '.closePopup', function (e) 
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.magnificPopup.close();
                });

    }
```

Comment: I dont want to bind it on button. there should be a generic function